# How to fetch data in PHP with MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried several times but cannot succeed in getting the right syntax—according to PHP 5.5.12  —to fetch single or multiple rows from my database.

```
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","doortolearn");
if (!$con) {
    echo "Could not connect to DBMS";       
}
    $query="select * from teacher where tremail='$_POST[email]' and trpasssword='$_POST[password]'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $flag=FALSE;
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
        $flag=TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: why no quotes around `$_POST[password]`

Comment: Always print your query,then you'll know what's was the prblm

Comment: guys, welcome to hackers heaven!!! **NEVER** use posted data directly to run query.

Comment: unhashed unsalted password - tisk tisk

Comment: `'$_POST[email]'` should be `'{$_POST['email']}'` you missed braces. but i don't recommend using it in your query

Comment: When you finish the site, let me know, my password is going to be `' OR 1`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php (which would also "fix" at least one of the issues)

Comment: i m a begginer till now... Please help me out, rather than increasing my probs

Comment: check these links also http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection or search google for `sql injection` you will get tons of resources at any level

Comment: check @JakeGould's solution. that is a good place to start

Comment: How do you get down from an elephant? You don't - you get down from a duck!  How do you you do this with mysqli? You don't, you do it with PDO. Especially if you are just learning, learn with PDO. Also, always use parameter binding for input from the user (which includes $_GET), and use `filter_input(INPUT_GET, <field>)`, don't access $_GET directly. And don't store the password in the database, store its `sha1()` hash.

Comment: @Mawg what does filter_input to do with thus question? What's wrong with mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have no single quotes `'` around `$_POST[password]`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE tremail='". $_POST['email'] ."' and trpasssword='" . $_POST['password'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$flag = FALSE;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $flag = TRUE;
}
```

But past that, do you even have a MySQL database connection set here? I see `$con` but is that really working?

Also, check if there are errors by adding `or die(mysql_error($con))` to your `mysqli_query($con, $query)` line.

Also, you have a `$_SESSION` value, but do you even set `session_start` at the beginning of your script?

But I also recommend you use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` for your values to at least escape them if you are not going to do basic validation:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE tremail=? and trpasssword=?";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ss', $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$flag = FALSE;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $flag = TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To successfully fetch data from MySQL using mysqli extension in PHP you need to perform more or less three actions: connect, execute prepared statement, fetch data.

**Connection:**

The connection is really simple. There should always be only 3 lines of code for opening a connection. You enable error reporting, create new instance of mysqli, and set the correct charset.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db_name');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

**Prepared statement**

This is the tricky part. You need to prepare SQL statement to be executed. **Careful, never concatenate PHP variables into SQL directly**. Bind the variables using placeholders. Once the statement is ready you can execute it on the server.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE tremail=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Fetch the data**

If your prepared statement should return some results, you need to fetch them and do something with the records. To fetch the result use `get_result()`. This will give you an object that you can iterate on to fetch each row one by one.

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['user_id'];
}
```

If you are only starting learning PHP, please consider learning [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It is easier to use and offers more functionality. Use mysqli only for legacy projects.

Answer (score -1):

**can You try this code**

---

```
<?php $query=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user");
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['age']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['mobile']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: please explain in detail your code if it is possible.

Answer (score -2):

```
$r =$mysqli->query("select * from users");

while ( $row =  $r->fetch_assoc() )
{
?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['pwd']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```