# Display an int value from SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm busy with a school project where I need to register users. I created the database and added the tables and can add users. What I just can't get right is to display the next available user id in the table.

I'm using php to retrieve the highest value but when I use echo the variable won't show. There is no error, there is no output at all, just the rest of the page.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'design');
        $query = "SELECT MAX(userid) AS userid FROM users" or 
                 die(mysql_error());
        $highest_id = mysqli_query($db, $query);             
        echo $highest_id;
?>
```

The code successfully connects to the database, the column is called userid, it contains int values and there are other columns as well.
All other code in the script runs perfectly, it's just this part that I can't get to work.

I have spent the last two days reading and searching for answers and I am at my wits end. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: die(mysql_error()) should be die(mysqli_error())

Comment: First learn how to fetch mysql data. For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028697/how-to-fetch-data-in-php-with-mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be your table is User and not Userid

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(userid) AS userid FROM users"
```

Anyway for fetching you should use eg:

```
$result  = mysqli_query($db, $query); 
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Thank you. You were correct the table name was incorrect. It should have been users, not userid. Your fetching advice got the job done. Thank you for the help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli_query returns a general object that contains the results array. You have to use the mysqli_fetch_row.

```
<?php
  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'design');
  $query = "SELECT MAX(userid) AS userid FROM userid" or die(mysql_error());
  $highest_id_query = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  var_dump($highest_id_query); // so you could check the object attributes

  //loop results from query
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($highest_id_query)){ 
   $highest_id = $row['userid'];
   echo $highest_id;
  }
?>
```

You could also use the sql statement: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userid

Be sure to name your tables correctly! SELECT COUNT(*) FROM **users**